# Performance of numpy sum and bottleneck nansum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, bottleneck-package

I've got a piece of code that is quiet heavily dependent on the use of `numpy` `sum`, about 60% of my time is spent on the calculation of just a few results and an replication of the offending code is shown below. This section of code (not including the array generation as this is passed in from external files) is then run thousands of times in each simulation as the data changes.

```py
import numpy as np

# generate some representative size example data
array_size = 100 # typical array_size range 100 - 5000 
weighting = np.random.random(array_size)
var_a = np.random.random(array_size)
var_b = np.random.random((array_size, 3))
var_c = np.random.random((array_size, 3))
var_d = np.random.random(array_size)
var_e = np.random.random(array_size)

# calculate results
res_1 = var_a * weighting
res_2 = np.sum(res_1)
res_3 = np.sum(var_b * var_a[:, np.newaxis], axis=0)
res_4 = np.sum(var_c * var_a[:, np.newaxis], axis=0)
res_5 = np.sum(res_1 / var_e)
res_6 = np.sum(var_d / res_1) / res_2
```

Running a few quick `timeit` benchmarks on the data gives a baseline of the time spent per call to the block of code:

```py
36.3 µs ± 579 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each) # array_size = 100
103 µs ± 2.88 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each) # array_size = 1000
360 µs ± 3.23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each) # array_size = 5000
```

In order to reduce my runtime I decided to replace `numpy.sum()` with bottleneck.nansum() as it seems to be optimised implementations of some numpy functions. Here's the ever so slightly modified bottleneck version:

```py
res_1 = var_a * weighting
res_2 = bn.nansum(res_1)
res_3 = bn.nansum(var_b * var_a[:, np.newaxis], axis=0)
res_4 = bn.nansum(var_c * var_a[:, np.newaxis], axis=0)
res_5 = bn.nansum(res_1 / var_e)
res_6 = bn.nansum(var_d / res_1) / res_2
```

And a quick `timeit` test shows that `bn.nansum` should be quicker than numpy:

```py
10.3 µs ± 222 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each) # array_size = 100
43 µs ± 1.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each) # array_size = 1000
177 µs ± 1.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each) # array_size = 5000
```

So this simple test suggests that my code should be significantly quicker if I replace `numpy.sum` with `bottleneck.nansum`. However, when I make that change in the code and then run a test, my code is about 5x slower overall with `bottleneck` being used, and `bottleneck` seems to take more than 10x longer to process these few changed lines, contradicting the `timeit` results.

I've just copied these lines from some profiler runs related to this:

```
ncalls | tottime | percall | cumtime | percall | filename:lineno(function)
83349   525.4   0.006303    525.4   0.006303    ~:0(<built-in method bottleneck.reduce.nansum>)

83349   0.2606  3.127e-06   55.69   0.0006681   fromnumeric.py:2188(sum)
101880  55.43   0.0005441   55.43   0.0005441   ~:0(<method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects>)
```

Does anyone have any idea why simple tests with `timeit` show `bottleneck` to be much quicker, but why the full code when the script is run is significantly slower when bottleneck is used? Is `timeit` doing something special hat doesn't happen under normal circumstances? Is there any way I can investigate this further to see what the problem is?

The only changes in the code are those few lines highlighted above - nothing else in my code changes. I'm quite surprised by this significant degrade in performance when using `bottleneck` instead of `numpy`.

Comment: Maybe check the dtype of the arrays? Also it looks like your percall in numpy is 0.000668 which is 668 us - Your arrays are probably closer to 10,000 sized. Maybe you can benchmark with 10,000 and 20,000 sized arrays? Also what kind of cpu usage do you get?

Comment: the `dtype` of all arrays is `np.float64` and all data is the same type except for the array shapes which are always (n,) or (n,3). My cpu usage seems relatively low in both cases, maybe 1 or two cores being utilised.

Comment: When I change the array size for the `timeit` runs, the trend is the same - `bottleneck` is 2-3x times faster than `numpy`. I can't change the size of the data within the simulation when running the profiler as I'm using the real datasets which generally average around 1000-1500 rows

Comment: Maybe you can try dumping the actual array used in the script into a pickle file and benchmark using the array from that file? Are you using any multithreading or multiprocessing that you haven't accounted for?

Comment: I think I've found the cause of the problem - I moved the test data that is loaded from one drive to another drive (both identical ssds, just one for the OS and one for data) and things are significantly quicker on the data drive compared to the OS drive. On the data drive the `bottleneck` code is quicker by about 2x. I think `Windows` is doing something funny here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with profiling the the code using the real data seems to have been caused by something being done by windows (indexing, etc), as moving the data to a data drive reduces the runtime significantly.

The runtime for the above code snippets reduces from 55s to 9s for the `numpy` code and from >500s to just 4s for the `bottleneck` code, which matches what the `timeit` timings show.

Sorry for the confusion.